# Why is the background of my Geoserver WMS+Leaflet example grey instead of transparent?

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wms, layers

I am trying to add a WMS layer to my leaflet map. When I add the layer it shows up but the the outside of the layer is grey instead of a world map.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html -->
<html>
<head>
<title> leaflet webviewer with Geoserver</title>
<!--Load the style stylesheet of leaflet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin=""/>
<!--Load leaflet -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-/Nsx9X4HebavoBvEBuyp3I7od5tA0UzAxs+j83KgC8PU0kgB4XiK4Lfe4y4cgBtaRJQEIFCW+oC506aPT2L1zw==" crossorigin=""></script>

  <!--Load vectorGrid plugin for Leaflet -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.vectorgrid@latest/dist/Leaflet.VectorGrid.bundled.js"></script>


<style>
/*Set the dimensions of our map */
.map {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<!--Create our map object -->
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
// Find our map id
var map = L.map('map')
// Set open openstreetmap
L.tileLayer(
      "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}",
      {
        // attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 20,
        minZoom: 5,
        zoom: 16,
        id: "mapbox/streets-v11",
        accessToken:
          "API CODE"
      }
    ).addTo(map);


    var wmsLayer= L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/nyc_roads/wms", {
        layers: 'nyc_roads:tiger-ny',
        transparent: true,
        format: 'image/png',
    });
    map.addLayer(wmsLayer);

// Set our initial location and zoomlevel
map.setView([40.712776, -74.005974], 6);


</script>
```

This is the result of the code:

[image: Result]

I do not understand what I am doing wrong and why the outside of the layer is not transparent.

Any help/ tips are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tiger-ny` group contains a layer called `giant_polygon` which is coloured grey to make the background look "nice". If you want it to be transparent leave that layer out of your request.

Answer (score 2):

Apperently I just used the wrong layer. I tried  to do the same thing with a other layer and that one was png.

I thought I could change the grey background to a transparrent background but I was wrong

I changed my code

From this:

```
var wmsLayer= L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/nyc_roads/wms", {
        layers: 'nyc_roads:tiger-ny',
        transparent: true,
        format: 'image/png',
    });
    map.addLayer(wmsLayer);
```

To This:

```
var wmsLayer= L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/nyc_roads/wms", {
    layers: 'nyc_roads:nyc_roads',
    transparent: true,
    format: 'image/png',
});
map.addLayer(wmsLayer);
```

This is the result of my code now. The only thing I changed is the Layer name.

[image]